# backbone.js collection.get() undefined

Tags: javascript, collections, backbone.js

I'm using Backbone, and I have a collection full of 7 models.

I want to grab one model and pull it from the collection. However, everything I try returns `undefined`.

Here is how I populate the collection

```
var coll = new TestCollection();
coll.fetch();
```

A simple console log call shows that the collection is populated from the JSON file

```
child
_byCid: Object
_byId: Object
_onModelEvent: function () { [native code] }
_removeReference: function () { [native code] }
length: 7
models: Array[7]
__proto__: ctor
```

However I have tried a whole bunch of approaches in order to grab one of these models from the collection including `coll.at(1)` and `coll.get(1)` but each returns `undefined`.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) method is an AJAX call and that means that it is asynchronous. Your `console.log` call puts a live reference into the console (so it is sort of asynchronous) so you end up with this sequence of events:

1. You call `coll.fetch()`.
2. Backbone sends off a `$.ajax` call.
3. You call `console.log(coll)` and a live reference goes in the console.
4. You call `coll.at(1)` or `coll.get(1)` and get nothing because **2** hasn't returned from the server yet.
5. **2**  comes back from the server and populates your collection.
6. Then you go look at the console but `coll` has been populated by now so the `coll` reference in the console includes the models that came back in **5**.
7. Confusion.

A successful [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) triggers a `"reset"` event so you should be listening to that event if you want to know when the collection is populated:

```
coll.on('reset', this.some_method);
```

Or, for a one-shot notification, you could use the `success` callback:

```
coll.fetch({
    success: function(collection, response) {
        //...
    }
});
```

---

In newer versions of Backbone, you need to pass the `reset: true` option to `fetch` if you want a reset event:

```
coll.fetch({ reset: true }); // This will now trigger a 'reset' event
```

Comment: Ahh this makes so much sense Thanks!